# Critical point of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $$f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
for $x\neq0$ and  $f(0) = 0$ .

Show that $0$ is a critical point of $f$ that is not a local maximum nor a local minimum nor an inflection point.

I need some help in order to show that.

If possible, give me only a hint, as it is homework and I only want some idea to finish the problem by myself.

Thanks a lot . ; )

Comment: Is it $f(0)=0$??I have edited it that way.

Comment: @White_ocean : What do you have to check for it to be a critical point?

Comment: @ Prahlad Vaidyanathan : I can find the critical point but I can't to show is not a local maximum nor a local minimum nor an inflection point.

Answer (score 2):

1. Prove it is a critical point (that the derivative exists and it is $0$).
2. Prove it is neither a maximum or a minimum by proving that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there are $x$ and $y$, $0<x<\varepsilon,0<y<\varepsilon$  such as $f(x)>f(0)$ and $f(y)<f(0)$ (and $f(-x)<f(0)$ and $f(-y)>f(0)$) so there is no neighborhood in which $0$ is maximum or minimum.
3. This also implies why it is not an inflection point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: think about what happens with the $\sin(1/x)$ part of the expression near zero. In a small neighborhood of the origin, you have infinitely many points of the form $2/k\pi$ (they accumulate near $0$) so your function oscillates infinitely many times between $-4/k^{2} \pi^{2}$ and $4/k^{2} \pi^{2}$ in that neighborhood, taking care of the maximum/minimum part of the question. Then look at the proper derivatives that give you the concavity and apply the same reasoning (notice that the $x^{2}$ factor is placed there exactly to give you sufficient smoothness to differentiate the function a certain number of times before it becomes discontinuous in $0$).

Comment: thank a lot ;)  
Carlos Eugenio Thomps   and  ulilaka  ขอบคุณค่ะ